# Multiprocess Python but running on different terminals to separately track responses delivered in each of the codes in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, time, terminal, multiprocessing

> Question originally asked on `Super User` and suggested deleting it from
> there and creating a new question here in the main community.

I have a code that runs non-stop, but **every 1 hour** it makes a call to another code.

The reason I need it is to be able to follow in real time the text delivered in each of the codes without them getting mixed up.

Is there any way to make this secondary code run completely separately from the main one?

A basic example would be this:

Code One (`Multiprocess_Part_1.py`):

```
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep
import Multiprocess_Part_2

def main():
    a = 1+1
    print(a)
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Multiprocess_Part_2.secondary)
    p1.start()
    sleep(10)
    main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Code Two  (`Multiprocess_Part_2.py`):

```
def secondary():
    b = 2+2
    print(b)
```

Terminal Result:

```
2
4
2
4
2
4
```

Expected response as if, for example, there was a way to run the second code in a separate terminal:

```
Terminal 1            Terminal 2
2                     4
2                     4
2                     4
2                     4
```

Visual expected example:

[image]

Comment: Side note: recursively calling `main()` is a bad idea. Use a loop.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні Not to mention not cleaning up the `multiprocessing` Processes...

Comment: Hi @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні , would you mind editing my question to adjust this issue you mentioned? I would greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi @AKX , would you mind editing my question to adjust this issue you mentioned? I would greatly appreciate the help to like a Andras!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't control how VSCode terminals are opened directly from within Python.

However, you seem to be on Windows; you could use [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) to start a new Python interpreter with a new terminal window:

```
os.system("start python Multiprocess_Part_2.py")
```

(or an equivalent `subprocess.call` invocation).

If you use virtualenvs, you'd want to use `sys.executable` instead of just `python` there, too.

```
# TODO: ensure this quoting is correct for Windows
os.system(f'start "{sys.executable}" Multiprocess_Part_2.py')
```

In other words, your script might become

```
import os
import time
import sys


def main():
    while True:
        os.system(f"start \"{sys.executable}\" Multiprocess_Part_2.py")
        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and your `Multiprocess_Part_2.py` would need to be able to run as a stand-alone program:

```
def secondary():
    b = 2+2
    print(b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    secondary()
```

Comment: Friend, I upvoted your answer but do you mind if I leave it open so more people can respond and I can see new views on the same case? Thank you very much in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Accepting an answer does not close the question in any way. People can respond just fine even if there's an accepted answer.

Comment: Oh okay then mate, thanks again!

Comment: why not use `f'some "text" more text'`, no need to escape `"`